# Typescript 2: how to add to existing interface or type?

Tags: typescript, interface

In `typescript 2`, the `window` object is of type `Window` -- an interface.

My code makes use of [`OfflineAudioContext`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OfflineAudioContext), a class accessible via the `window` object that typescript does not know about:

```
let offlineCtx = new window.OfflineAudioContext(2,44100*40,44100);
//TS Error: Property 'OfflineAudioContext' does not exist on type 'Window'
```

The code is transpiled and runs without problem, but I would like to get rid of this error. Is it possible to add to the `Window` type in a custom `d.ts` or to solve my issue some other way?

Comment: Have you had a look at the handbook? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/writing-declaration-files.html

Comment: @FabianLauer no; thanks for the link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add you own declarations to existing types and Typescript will automatically merge them. This is covered in the [Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) part of the docs.

In your case you can just add:

```
type OfflineAudioContextConstructor {
    new (num1: number, num2: number, num3: number): OfflineAudioContext;
}

interface Window {
    OfflineAudioContext: OfflineAudioContextConstructor;
}
```